# PlotLegends don't match the plot's curves

Tags: plotting, legending

Can anyone help me make the legends(markers) match with the figure curves?
I have 2 figures that have three curves each, and then I have to combine them.
I used the following code for the first figure:

```
 p1 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[{k, #}] & /@ {K11s, K12s, K22s}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[LineLegend[{"K11", "K12", "K22"}, 
 LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0] & )], {0.8, 
  0.2}], FrameLabel -> {"k", "K"}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True, 
  AxesStyle -> Directive[{Bold, 25}, {Black, 25}], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 14}, 
   PlotRange -> All]
```

for the other figure I used this:

```
p2 = Legended[Show[
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{k, #}] & /@ {K11b}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
   ListLinePlot[Transpose[{k, #}] & /@ {K12b}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashing[Large], Thickness[Large], Blue}], 
 ListLinePlot[Transpose[{k, #}] & /@ {K22b}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed}],
  AxesStyle -> Directive[{Bold, 25}, {Black, 25}], 
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "K"}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> 700, Background -> Transparent, PlotRange -> All, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 14}], 
 Placed[LineLegend[{Red, {Dashing[Large], Thickness[Large], 
  Blue}, {Dashed, Blue}}, {Style["fitted K11", 12], 
  Style["fitted K12", 12], Style["fitted K22", 12]}, 
  LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
  LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0] & ) , 
  LabelStyle -> {(FontFamily -> "Helvetica"), 
   FontWeight -> Bold}], {0.4, 0.8}]]
```

Then I combined them using "Show".
My problem with the second one is the markers do not match the one in the plot.Also is there another way to make these plots in one graph rather than using "Show" with keeping the legends bar inside the graph?

Comment: try using `Directive[Dashing[Large], Thickness[Large], Blue]` instead of `{Dashing[Large], Thickness[Large], Blue]}` and `Directive[Dashed, Blue]` instead of `{Dashed, Blue}` in `lListPlot`s and in `LineLegend` in `p2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
k = Range[10];
{K11s, K12s, K22s} = RandomInteger[10, {3, 10}];
{K11b, K12b, K22b} = {K11s, K12s, K22s} + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 10}]; 

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{k, #}] & /@ {K11s, K12s, K22s, K11b, K12b, K22b},
 PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, 
   Red, Directive[Dashing[Large], Thickness[Large], Blue], Directive[Dashed, Blue]}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[
     Flatten[{#, "fitted " <> # & /@ #}] &@{"K11", "K12", "K22"}, 
     LegendLayout -> {"Column", 2}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 20}, 
     LegendFunction -> (Framed[#1, FrameMargins -> 0] &)], 
   {0.35, 0.85}], 
 FrameLabel -> {"k", "K"}, Axes -> True, Frame -> True, 
 AxesStyle -> Directive[{Bold, 25}, {Black, 25}], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> Bold, FontSize -> 14}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: @Ghady, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.